# CAS for finite-dimensional complex representations of $S_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, computer-algebra

Does there exist a computer algebra system that can work with finite-dimensional complex representations of the symmetric groups on finitely many letters? It should have the following functionality: (1) a way to produce all the irreps (e.g. via Specht modules) (2) irreps should come with a preferred choice of basis and there should be a function mapping a given permutation to the corresponding matrix (3) a way to take tensor products, direct sums, symmetric and exterior powers (4) a function giving the decomposition into irreps for an arbitrary finite-dimensional complex representation.

SageMath does have (1) and (2) but not (3) as far as I know. It probably is possible to do everything except (2) in some combinatorics packages but (2) is essential here.

Comment: have a look at the magma handbook at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/650 (there is an online calculator anyone can access)